# Replace an element in a string of csv bash

Tags: bash

Working on a bash script. I'm reading a line from a properties file using `grep` and `cut` and have fetched some value in a variable `role_portions` something like this `role_portions=role_1:10,role_2:25,role_3:75,role_4:50,role_5:75,role_6:25,role_7:50`

Now, I get a few roles as csv input parameter in my bash script and I would want to change those roles values to 0.
For example, when I run `modify_script.sh role_2,role_4,role_7`, after reading the above value from the file, the script should provide as output  `role_1:10,role_2:0,role_3:75,role_4:0,role_5:75,role_6:25,role_7:0`. Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the role names are without special characters (like `&` and `/`) you can use  `sed`.

```
for role in role_2 role_4 role_7; do
  role_portions=$(sed -r "s/(^|,)(${role}):[^,]*/\1\2:0/" <<< "${role_portions}")
done
```

When you are already using `grep` and `cut` you might be able to combine commands (maybe use `awk`).